# Going from individual elements back to to matrix/vector notation

Tags: linear-algebra

*[Context: I'm working through [problem set one of Andrew Ng's Machine Learning course, question 2](http://see.stanford.edu/materials/aimlcs229/problemset1.pdf), trying to derive the Hessian myself. My trouble, though, is with the simple linear algebra. I'll ignore the regularization parameters in my question to keep things simple.]*

I can find $H_{jk}$ by taking partial derivatives of the original function with respect to $j$ and $k$. I've worked it through to the point where I know that $H_{jk} = \sum_{i=1}^m d_i X_{ij} X_{ik}$, and I know the answer is that $H = X^TDX$.

($d$ is a vector of reals, $H$, $X$ and $D$ are $m \times m$ matrices, $D$ diagonal with $D_{ii} = d_i$.)

It's easy for me to verify that $H = X^TDX$ gives $H_{jk} = \sum_{i=1}^m d_i X_{ij} X_{ik}$. But I don't "see" how to go easily in the opposite direction.

1) Is there a method, or a set of rules to memorize, or a way of talking through it that would make it easy, or do I just need to do enough basic linear algebra homework to start to recognize patterns?

2) Am I doing it wrong by breaking it down and deriving $H_{jk}$? Are there tricks for taking these kind of derivatives (which involve logs and exponentials) over the whole matrix at once?

Comment: There is only one pattern you need to recognize, and it's what a product of two matrices looks like in coordinates. And you shouldn't memorize this pattern; you should understand how it follows from the fact that matrices model linear transformations.

Comment: I recognize the product of _two_ matrices in coordinates, but that didn't help me here.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have found the answer. The key insight is that multiplication by diagonal matrices multiplies each *row* $i$ by $D_{ii}$ when the diagonal matrix is on the left, and each *column* $i$ by $D_{ii}$ when the diagonal matrix is on the right.

Thus $\sum_{i=1}^m d_i X_{ij} X_{ik}$ can be rewritten as $\sum_{i=1}^m X_{ij} (DX)_{ik}$ = $\sum_{i=1}^m X_{ji}^T (DX)_{ik}$, which is a simple product of $X^T$ and $(DX)$.